Issue with snowflake extension on VS CODE
So I'm new to snowflake and I tried to install the extension on VS CODE but the snowflake icon on the right side bar is loading forever and I have a runtime message :
webview/context is a proposed menu identifier. It requires 'package.json#enabledApiProposals: ["contribWebviewContext"]' and is only available when running out of dev or with the following command line switch: --enable-proposed-api snowflake.snowflake-vsc
How can I fix this ?
I tried to modify the 'package.json' but nothing changed.

Hi what version of VS code are you using , if its an older version then you may need to upgrade the VS version. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70
